# How to Have Both "Return" and "Done" Options in Android Keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-layout, keyboard

I have an android notepad app that uses an EditText. When the users begins typing in the edit text I want them to have the option to exit the keyboard with a "done" button or go to the next line with a "Return" button. I cannot find a way to make the keyboard include both the done and return buttons. If there is any way to make this happen that would be great.

I know one way to do this might be to add a top border to the keyboard with a "Done" button in it. I have researched that as well and I cannot find out how to make a top border appear when the keyboard becomes visible. If that is the best way to do it, I would like to know how to do that also. I have managed to make borders already on the screen resize with the keyboard with adjustResize, but I want to make the border only exist if the keyboard is visible. That is where I'm stuck.

Here are my views:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
The main EditText that covers the entire activity.
It is attached to the LinedEditor class which
gives it the "notepad" look.
-->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <view
        class = "com.patrickslagle.notepad.NewNote$LinedEditor"
        android:id="@+id/note"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
        android:paddingStart="60dp"
        android:paddingTop= "25dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_border"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/note"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my current bottom border:

```
<!--
The bottom menu bar where the user chooses actions.
-->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_border"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="@string/delete_button"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bullets"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bullets"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:background="@color/yellow" />

        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="@string/save_button"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_save_24dp"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mail"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/mail"
            android:background="@color/yellow" />

        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="@string/menu_desc"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_24dp"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/save"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/save"
            android:background="@color/yellow" />

        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="@string/bullet"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/bullets"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_format_list_bulleted_24dp"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mail"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mail"
            android:background="@color/yellow" />

        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="@string/mail_symbol"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/mail"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_email_24dp"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/yellow" />

        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="@string/clear"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/clear_note"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_24dp"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/yellow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's a screenshot of my app if it helps:

[Notepad Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KewDw.png)

Comment: You could also hide keyboard when the user touches outside of the keyboard instead of having a done button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Google design guides, e.g. http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html, you don't need an extension of the keyboard:

- The back key on the device (hard or soft) will just let the keyboard go away.
- If you need another action, like "save changes", you should place an action button at the top of the screen. This can also be clicked while the keyboard is still open, so no additional click is needed.

Following the design rules will make your app easier to use, as it will behave similar to other well-known apps. In contrast, an app that brings its own keyboard layout might confuse users.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful.